# Error only static members can be accessed in initializers

Tags: flutter

I am trying to render a list of settings. Each setting has a different controller. For example the controller could be a switch. Or a button.

**Setting Class**

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';

class Setting
{
  String key;
  Widget controller;

  Setting(this.key, this.controller);
}
```

But when I try to make a list as a field it says that it can only static members so I cannot use the variables and funtions. How can I declare this List inside the item builder directly? Maybe a spread operator with .toList()? I'm not really sure how I would write it.
**Settings Page State**

```
class _TheSettingsPageState extends State<TheSettingsPage> {

  bool _isMilesPerHour = globals.preferences.speedNotation.isMilesPerHour;
  bool _isKilometersPerHour = globals.preferences.speedNotation.isKilometersPerHour;
  File _pickedImage;
  List<Setting> settings = [
    Setting
    (
      SpeedNotation.milesPerHour.shortNotation,
      Switch(
        value: _isMilesPerHour, 
        onChanged: _onMilesPerHourToggled
      ),
    ),
    Setting
    (

    ),
    Setting
    (

    ),
  ];

  _onMilesPerHourToggled(bool isMilesPerHour){
    setState(() {
      _isMilesPerHour = isMilesPerHour;
      _isKilometersPerHour = !isMilesPerHour;
    });
    globals.preferences.writeSettings();
  }

  _onKilometersPerHourToggled(bool isKilometersPerHour){
    setState(() {
      _isKilometersPerHour = isKilometersPerHour;
      _isMilesPerHour = !isKilometersPerHour;
    });
    globals.preferences.writeSettings();
  }

  Future getImageAsync() async{
    File image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    setState(() {
      _pickedImage = image;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).backgroundColor,
      body: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
          child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: 
          [ 
            Expanded(
              flex: 1,
              child: Row
              (
                children: [
                  Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                    child: NavigatePopButton(),
                  ),
                  Spacer(),
                  Align
                  (
                    alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                    child: Text
                    (
                      'Settings',
                      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.title,
                      overflow: TextOverflow.visible,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Spacer(),
                ],
              )
            ),
            Expanded(
              flex: 4,
              child: MediaQuery.removePadding(
                context: context,
                removeTop: true,
                child: ListView.separated(
                  itemCount: 2,
                  separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => Divider(height: 1.0), 
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
                      return settings[index].controller;
                  }       
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ]
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Move the assignment of `settings` into `initState()` (override it, if you haven't already)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing all initializations inside `initState()`

Something like this

```
class _TheSettingsPageState extends State<TheSettingsPage> {

  bool _isMilesPerHour = globals.preferences.speedNotation.isMilesPerHour;
  bool _isKilometersPerHour = globals.preferences.speedNotation.isKilometersPerHour;
  File _pickedImage;
  List<Setting> settings;

  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    settings = [
      Setting(
        SpeedNotation.milesPerHour.shortNotation,
        Switch(
          value: _isMilesPerHour,
          onChanged: _onMilesPerHourToggled,
        ),
      ),
      Setting(),
      Setting(),
    ];
  }
}
```